# Specify binary order in sql query

Tags: 7, database

In custom module which selects field (collation: utf8_latvian_ci) from database ordered ouput gives wrong alphabetical order:
**"Aaaa, Āaaa, Abb, Acc"** instead of **"Aaaa, Abb, Acc, Āaaa"**.
This can be corrected by query like this

```
[..] ORDER BY myfield COLLATE utf8_bin
```

and then I can get correct order.

Here is my query from custom module:

```
  $query = db_select($table, 'd');
  $query
    ->fields('d', array('myfield1', 'myfield1'))
    ->condition('d.field1', $field1, '=')
    ->orderBy('field1');
  $return = $query->execute();
```

Can I specify ORDER collation using Drupal's query structure? Or only workarounds can help?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `db_query()`? Unless your query is being built dynamically (doesn't look like it from your code), that would be the better solution anyway

Comment: Yep, it is build dinamically. Query goes through a lot of IFs and conditions. So if there is no other way around then all of it should be rewritten from the scratch.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `->orderBy('field1 COLLATE utf8_bin')`? Might just work, I don't think the order by clauses are altered